# Published documents filter based on user.profile.prop

Tags: meteor

This Meteor App needs to publish records to each user based on the value of `user.profile.group` but it is publishing the whole set, i.e. not filtering.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? thx

```js
//lib/collections.js
MenuItemsCol = new Mongo.Collection('menuItemsCol');

//client/main.js
Meteor.subscribe('menuItemsCol');

//server/publications.js
MenuItemsCol.remove({app: 'abc'});
lib.mainMenuItems.forEach(function (item) {
  if (item.app === 'abc') {
    MenuItemsCol.insert(item);
  }
});

Meteor.publish('menuItemsCol', function () {
  let menuGroup = '';
  if (this.userId) {
    menuGroup = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}).profile.menuGroup;
  }
  return MenuItemsCol.find({app: 'abc'}, {group: {$in: menuGroup.split('')}}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}});
});

//db.users.find(this.userId) shows
profile" : {
        "menuGroup" : "g"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first argument for find() is the filter, the second is the options. you are supplying 3 arguments, and it looks like the first two are meant to be your filter:

```
return MenuItemsCol.find({app: 'abc'}, {group: {$in: menuGroup.split('')}}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}});
```

i think you mean this:

```
return MenuItemsCol.find({
      app: 'abc',
      group: {$in: menuGroup.split('')}
    }, 
    {
      sort: {createdAt: 1}
    });
```